# Why isn't my f:param rendering inside h:outputText?

Tags: jsf, parameters, message

I have a message.properties file which contains:

```
success_text=How cool... You have guessed the number.  {0} is correct!
```

I have a JSF which contains:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg.success_text}" >
    <f:param value="#{numberBean.userNumber}" />
</h:outputText>
```

No matter what the value of  is, the HTML comes out:

> How cool... You have guessed the number.  {0} is correct!

Why isn't `{0}` changing to the value indicated in the `<f:param>` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `<f:param>` isn't supported by [`<h:outputText>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/outputText.html). It works in [`<h:outputFormat>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/outputFormat.html) only.

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msg.success_text}" >
    <f:param value="#{numberBean.userNumber}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```